# Сортировка текста и вырезание лишнего

Tags: python-3.x, сортировка

Спарсил страницу с одного сайта и минимизировал вывод до такого:

> Событие 1   06.02.2019 15:05 Событие 2 07.02.2019 13:34
>   Событие 3   08.02.2019 10:33 Событие 4
>   08.02.2019 13:51","settings":null},{"command":"insert","method":"prepend","selector":null,"data":"","settings":null}]

Как в Python 3 отсортировать данные в такой вид и убрать лишнее :

> Событие 1   06.02.2019 15:05
>   Событие 2   07.02.2019 13:34
>   Событие 3   08.02.2019 10:33
>   Событие 4   08.02.2019 13:51

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно выполнить эту задачу с использованием рег.выражений:

```
import re
inp = "Событие 1 06.02.2019 15:05 Событие 2 07.02.2019 13:34 Событие 3 08.02.2019 10:33 Событие 4 08.02.2019 13:51"
inp = inp.replace("\n", "") # удаляем символы перевода строки (хоть сейчас в inp их нету)

# по заданному рег.выражению получаем все совпадения
results = re.findall(r"([а-яА-Я]+\s(\d)\s(\d{2}\.\d{2}.\d{4})\s(\d{2}:\d{2}))", inp)
# Структура кортежей списка results:
# 0: Вся строка
# 1: номер события
# 2: дата
# 3: время

# сортируем наш массив
sortedResults = sorted(results, key=lambda x: int(x[1]))
print(sortedResults)
# [
#    ('Событие 1 06.02.2019 15:05', '1', '06.02.2019', '15:05'),
#    ('Событие 2 07.02.2019 13:34', '2', '07.02.2019', '13:34'),
#    ('Событие 3 08.02.2019 10:33', '3', '08.02.2019', '10:33')
# ]
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!